# Bounded Linear Operator and the Adjoint

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, linear-transformations, adjoint-operators

Let $S$ be a linear operator with dense domain $\mathcal{D}(S)$ in the Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$. Assume that the  domain $\mathcal{D}(S)$ belongs to a larger domain, namely $\mathcal{D}(S) \subset \mathcal{D}(T)$, where $T$ is a bounded linear operator.

Given the aforementioned setup is it true that:

1) The domain $\mathcal{D}(T)$ is dense in $\mathcal{H}$.

2) The linear operator $S$ is bounded on $\mathcal{D}(S)$.

The reason that I ask 1) and 2) is that I am trying to deduce information about the adjoint operators $S^*$ and $T^*$ given the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $T$ is bounded then $D(T)=H$ by definition. Therefore, $2$ is false as well.

Comment: No why what by definition what?!

Comment: A bounded linear operator may even have trivial domain: $\mathcal{D}(T)=(0)$

Comment: @Freeze_S: Really!! If $D(T)=0$, then $T$ is the $0$ operator, and hence $D(T)=H$. The definition of a bounded operator is that it's defined everywhere. See any text on operator algebras.

Comment: Yes because operator algebra studies $\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H})$ as a space in its own right while operator theory adresses an operator $T:\mathcal{D}(T)\to\mathcal{H}$ as an individual object. *(Think of for example the BLT which is a very common tool.)*

Comment: @Freeze_S: I am not familiar with BLT. Maybe we are talking at cross purposes here.

Comment: BLT=Extension of Bounded Operators *(No idea why people here call it this way.)* I agree with you that when talking about bounded operators one is concerned with those acting on the whole space but this question specifically addresses the case of a dense domain. That is definitely a legitimate question also as many operators arise this way.

Answer (score 1):

*You might be looking for...*

A bounded operator is closable with:
$$\|T\|<\infty:\quad\mathcal{D}(\overline{T})=\overline{\mathcal{D}(T)}$$

*(Or similarly, a bounded operator is closed iff its domain is so.)*